# Using a session variable in a php mysql query with like

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, sql-like

I've been trying to create a search for my website and when I try using the variable as in

```
SELECT size FROM tires WHERE size = $size'
```

I don't get any results for my search. I do get a result that says

```
object(PDO)#@(0) {}
```

but I'm not sure why. I've tried hardcoding my search and it works perfectly. I've also tried

```
"SELECT size FROM tires WHERE size LIKE '%$size%'"
```

and this gives me all the results from the database if I use fetchAll. It gives me a partial result if I use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and I only want the results from what I put into the search box. HERE is the code that I have for the search:

```
    <?php
require('database_connection.php');
$lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; //2 weeks in seconds
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, '/');
session_start();
//require_once('includes/functions.php');
include('index.html');
if(isset($_POST['size'])){
$_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];
$size = $_SESSION['size'];

}




function tiresize() {
     global $db;

if (isset($_POST['size'])){ 
$_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];
$size = $_SESSION['size'];
       // $size=mysql_real_escape_string($size);
       // trim($size);
    }


    if (isset($size)){
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT size FROM tires WHERE size = '$size'");
    $query->execute();

    $tires = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($tires as $name) {
        echo "Tire Size: " .$name['size'];
         if($query) // will return true if successful else it will     return   false 
        { 
            echo 'Query is working';// code here for true
        };}}}
tiresize();



var_dump($db);

?>
```

The var_dump($db) gives a object(PDO)#1(0){}

HERE IS THE FORM:

```
 <table><form action="search.php" method="post">
<tr><td>
<p>
<label for="searchSize" id="searchSize">Search Size:</label>
</p>
</td><td>
<p>
<input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="<?php echo          $size['size']; ?> " /><br /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="size" value="Search" /> 
</p>
</td></tr></form>
</table>
```

Comment: Afwul code bro. `PDO` and `mysql` functions mixed I've never seen somebody done that before. Use prepared statements against sql injections.

Comment: Sorry - I'm just learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "`global $size;`" is used inside a function, it imports `$size` variable from global scope, which perhaps is `NULL` and overwrites local `$size` variable. Have you checked the `$size` value after `global` statement?

Comment: I removed the global statements and it is still doing the same thing. Thank you though.

Comment: Didn't you mean to get $size from $_POST rather than from $_SESSION? Have you set size in $_SESSION before?

Comment: I got the size from a post first and then set it in a session, which is probably unnecessary, but that's what I did. Thanks.

Comment: OK, but I can't see that you set it in the session in this function tiresize, so apparently you do it somewhere else in the code. Question is if you called session_start() before that. If however all you do is in this function, it cannot work because you don't set size in the session here.

Comment: I set the session start at the beginning of the page and used this to set it: if(isset($_POST['size'])){
$_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];
$size = $_SESSION['size']; I'm still learning, so please tell me if I did it wrong and let me know if you can think of any other reason my search won't work. I've worked on it for days now.

Comment: Question is if you called session_start() at the top of that page to have access to $_SESSION. I don't see entire page, just one function, so there may be plenty of reasons. One of them will be the one I have put in my answer, which I hope will be accepted as correct after you work out those other issues which I cannot see before seeing whole page.

Comment: I did remove the global from the variables to try and see if your first answer worked and it didn't. It still isn't working and I will happily post the entire page if you think that would help. It's just basically the search function though.

Comment: OK, but you never answered what is the value of $size just before $db->prepare - just var_dump it to see what is in that variable. If it yields all rows, it can mean that is empty.

Comment: var_dump($size) is string(6) "Search"

Comment: I guess "Search" is a value of your input, instead of a label, your form is probably wrongly designed. I would need to see index.html, or at least the form.

Comment: I posted the form. It might be something to do with it... I hope so. Thank YOU very much.

Comment: The name of the input submit is the same as of text input, therefore $_POST['size'] yields "Search". Change the submit name to for example "size_submit" and the condition to if(isset($_POST['size_submit'])). You don't even need to change the "if" condition - when you submit the form, $_POST['size'] will be set as well.

Comment: You were right. My form was causing the problem. I still am not quite there with the way I have everything designed, but this is a step in the right direction. I tried to say your answer was correct, but it said I need a 15 reputation and I'm not there yet, but I really appreciate your help - God bless you and thanks again!!!!

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could help. So maybe you can upvote this answer instead, I don't know what reputation you need to have to do this...